# Why using forward_list with char is much more optimize than using it with long long?

Tags: c++, list, optimization, c++11, forward-list

I used below code for comparing `std::list` with `std::forward_list`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER start_;
    LARGE_INTEGER end_;
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    std::list<long long> list;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start_);
    for(long long i=0;i<50000000;i++)
        list.push_front(i);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end_);


    std::cout<< (end_.QuadPart - start_.QuadPart) / (freq.QuadPart / 1000) <<"\n";
    cin.get();
}
```

I changed list with `forward_list`  .
and measured time and size of both 
result :

```
//long long
//              size    time
//forward list 1157.3  2360
//list         1157.3  2450
```

And I do the same for this code :

```
int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER start_;
    LARGE_INTEGER end_;
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    std::list<char> list;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start_);
    for(long long i=0;i<50000000;i++)
        list.push_front('a');
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end_);


    std::cout<< (end_.QuadPart - start_.QuadPart) / (freq.QuadPart / 1000 )<<"\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Result :

```
//char  
//              size  time
//forward list  773   2185
//list          1157  2400
```

The question is why using `std::forward_list`  whith char  is much better than using it with long long comparing to `std::list` .

I know speeds are almost same but what about the size of containers ?

```
//long long
//             size(mb)    time
//forward list 1157.3      2360
//list         1157.3      2450


//char  
//              size(mb)  time
//forward list  773       2185
//list          1157      2400
```

Comment: Free chart porn: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F8lmLjFtIrDJb_FUauP1L_7m6bsiLFJSv2hyLV3tI3o/edit?usp=sharing (results collected on my machine). Do you still think there's a significant difference between any of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forward_list` is typically implemented as a simple singly-linked list. The list nodes have a single pointer that designates the following node in the list, and a data field that holds the actual user data. The size of a single node of a `forward_list<T>` would then be `sizeof(void*) + sizeof(T)` assuming (1) that all data pointers have the same size, and (2) `T` does not have a more strict alignment than `void*`.

`list` is implemented as a double-linked list. As such, a single node would have a data field and pointers to both the next and the previous list nodes. The size of a `list<T>` node is thus `2 * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(T)` under the same assumptions as above.

It is common for memory allocators to allocate memory in blocks whose size is a multiple of the largest fundamental alignment. There's a tradeoff between providing the granularity of allocations and the amount of tracking overhead. Allocating blocks in multiples of the fundamental alignment is a good balance point and has the added bonus of ensuring that allocations are always properly aligned for any type that is not over-aligned.

Let's make the assumption that your program is running on a 32-bit implementation - `sizeof(void*) == 4` - and that the system allocator uses a block size of 8 bytes - `sizeof(double)`. These assumptions are true for typical 32-bit Windows C++ as implemented by MS Visual C++. With those assumptions, the size of various objects are:

- `forward_list<char>` node: `sizeof(void*) + sizeof(char) == 5`, which the memory allocator will round up to an 8 byte allocation.
- `forward_list<long long>` node: `sizeof(void*) + sizeof(long long) == 12`, which the memory allocator will round up to an 16 byte allocation.
- `list<char>` node: `2 * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(char) == 9`, which the memory allocator will round up to an 16 byte allocation.
- `list<long long>` node: `2 * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(long long) == 16`, which the memory allocator won't round since 16 is already a multiple of 8.

So of the types in the OP, `forward_list<char>` allocates 8 bytes per element and all of `list<char>`, `list<long long>`, and `forward_list<long long>` allocate 16 bytes per element. This is one likely explanation for the memory usage observations.

Answer (score 6):

First thing to note is that this is hardly "much better". The difference is entirely marginal.

Beyond that, I think it's fairly obvious that copying 8 bytes is going to take slightly longer than copying one; plus, there is no read from register/memory required for your constant `'a'`, whose value can be hard-coded into your executable.

Comment: @omid: Not sure why you think this is substantial.